# Getting Elevation for many coordinates

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, elevation

I have a text file with many lats and longs, and I am trying to get their elevation. I found a website that already does that but it takes 500 only at a time, I have 1 million points. Is there any kind of service that does such thing?

Answer (score 3):

The google maps API elevation service is limited to prevent abuse.  There is publicly available elevation data:

http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/

Create your own service.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use geonames.org.  You can purchase a commercial account to have higher rate limits.  One of the services geonames.org offers is elevation from the SRTM data.  See http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html