# How to find the elevation of a lon/lat polygon

Tags: google-maps, gis, polygon, postgis, elevation

I am trying to create an application that uses terrain information about an area. I use lon/lat (4326) polygons from a kml file and store the geometries in postgis.

I need to find the elevation fluctuations of a particular area (polygon) defined by lon/lat points. How is this possible? I have read certain possible solutions like DEM but i do not how to use them.
Is there any other way of achieving it?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly there is a Google Elevation API :) (mainly for Android development, you need to register for a proper key):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/

Maybe you could use the JavaScript API of the same service (I haven't tried this one, just found the link from the previous one):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/services#Elevation

Probably you can us it, but beware of this:

> Use of the Google Elevation API is subject to a limit of 2,500 requests per day.

The good thing is that in one request you can get elevation data about a *Line*, with arbitrary number of divider points (the dividers are sectioning the line into equal length sections).

Comment: Does it apply in my situation? I mean that i have an entiry polygon to look for its elevation. How is this possible?

Comment: Make a orthogonal matrix, and with a number of queries (either by row, or by column, which is less) you can get the elevations in the section points. From this you can interpolate the required points.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948151/getting-elevation-for-many-coordinates  but i have no idea how to use such data.

Comment: 1. Write a program that fetches the elevation data, and stores e.g. in a database. (columns: x, y, lon, lat, elevation) 2. write your program that uses the gathered data. BTW, what do you want to do with those data?

Comment: 1,2 goes for your solution or the one posted on the relevant post? I have a polygon and i need to know if there are elevation fluctuations (possible mountains) in which may block a cameras view.

Comment: OK, I found your previous question, that explains enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329650/exclude-mountains-lakes-etc-in-lat-lon-polygon BTW, you can get the terrain type from the Google Elevation API as well (water, land, maybe city - there are docs about it)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22865/discussion-between-michelangelo-vandilakis-and-gaborsch)